# How to count number of measured values in Zabbix?

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I'm collection information from managed hosts to Zabbix by using SNMP. I'm getting number of values. We can imagine it as loads on each CPU core.

I would like to get number of the measured values - like number of the CPU cores.

Do you know how to do that?

Best regards

Comment: Do you wish to do it via the API, via the frontend, or via another item? Do you need the total number of items on a host or a total number of items with a particular key pattern? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Hi asaveljevs, I tried to monitor utilization of CPU on each core and on all cores as global. I would like to define calculated value for total CPU utilization, but I don't know how to summarize them. The number of cores is different as per appliance. Thank you ...

Comment: So Zabbix discovers SNMP items like cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, ..., cpuN, and you wish to automatically create a calculated item that does something like cpu1+cpu2+cpu3+...+cpuN? If so, I do not think there is currently a way to do this, but this feature request is tracked at https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1420 .

Comment: thank you asaveljevs for your answer. I assume that this is not currently implemented, but I need to be sure. We will try to find out some workaround for this. Once this will be implemented, I will keep this question updated. Many thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise to take a look at [calculated](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) & [aggregated](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate) items docs.

This example seems to do similar thing you require:

```
Example 4

Average CPU load on all hosts in multiple host groups.

grpavg[["Servers A","Servers B","Servers C"],system.cpu.load,last]
```